# How to access a OpenVPN network from a site that blocks most ports?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I would like to access my office, but I can't get in because the site (a coffee shop) has seemed to have blocked many ports.  My networking knowledge is a bit lacking but I think it is possible to tunnel all ports through an open port like 80 or 443 and have it reconstituted on the other side to the correct ports.  Unfortunately, that's as far as I got.

Anyone have any suggestions?  My company is using OpenVPN.  I'm not sure what version the server is running but the client is OpenVPN GUI v1.0.3.

A

Answer (score 0):

Try use [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) and configure OpenVPN client on using TOR SOCKS proxy.

add line to openvpn config:

```
socks-proxy 127.0.0.1 9050
```

Once it help me.
Tor slow, primary it enlarge latency around +100ms, but it really sophisticated in censorship bypassing.

Better, if it possible, support OpenVPN on TCP 443 as alternative port, special for cases like this, but it need configuring in Your office.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot.  But does this means that the connection is being encrypted twice?

Comment: Yes, at least twice. So You can not trust to tor encryption.
For performance You can lover anonymity in tor config to minimum.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  I can't trust tor encryption? Doesn't this make it even more secure although slightly slower?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work.  I set the TOR's proxy settings to the same ones as you stated for the OpenVPN.  Is that correct?

Comment: Like this? http://i.imgur.com/OEJF07O.png

Comment: I mean, TOR exit nodes can sniff traffic, so You anyway can't trust it in confidentiality. It only censorship bypass and anonymity tool.
You anyway need second layer of encryption, thah You can trust end to end from client to VPN server.

Comment: Ah, of course.  That I knew. :)

Comment: If You use original OpenVPN client, Browser proxy may be not important (at least I do it in other way). I configure socks in OpenVPN config itself. Somewhere in Program files/Openvpn is *.ovpn file with text config for connection.

Comment: Ah, so the proxy on the TOR browser is unnecessary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20986/discussion-between-mmv-ru-and-adrian).